# How to chain a Promise that expect parameters values from an Observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, observable

I have an observable that retrieve data, these values are parameters from a Promise. What is the better way to join these values in order that the Promises expected the values from observable and this no causes errors?

```
let user, id, settings;


this.UserService.getUserData().subscribe(user => {
    user = user.name;
    id = user.id;
});

this.UserConfiguration.getSettings(user, id)
    .then(res => {
      settings = res.settings;
      debugger
  });
```

Other way is call the promise in the observable, but I am not sure What is the best way to pass the paramenters into the observable.

```
this.UserService.getUserData().subscribe(user => {
    this.UserConfiguration.getSettings(user.name, user.id)
        .then(res => {
          settings = res.settings;
          debugger
    });
});
```

Comment: It's a little difficult to understand what you are asking. Do you want to know how to merge the results of two `Observable`s into one?

Comment: I am tried to obtein the better way to obtein the paramenter and then pass into the promise, in this one is getting the values from obsevable and then will assing to variables, other way is call the promise in the observable.

Comment: The first alternative won't work. The second alternative might. Did you try the second? Wasn't it working?

Comment: The first alternative is working, seems the asycronus assignation is passing the parameters in a right way, but I want to know a better way.

Comment: `.then(resolvedData)`? Isn't that what `.then` is for?

Comment: The first one doesn't look like it should be working. It would immediately call `getSettings` while `user` and `id` are still `undefined`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.UserService.getUserData().switchMap((data) => 
    Observable.fromPromise(this.UserConfiguration.getSettings(data.user, data.id))
    .subscribe((result) => this.settings = result.settings));
```

**EDIT:** I'm simplifying the answer to include only the non-lettable version.  If you need lettable operators, just `pipe(switchMap).subscribe()` instead.